# Rails geocoder gem reverse geocoding address format customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I am using the geocoder gem to reverse geocode a location given the latitude and longitude of an object. This works great, however, I would like to change the result so that only the desired part of the complete address is shown.

In some specific cases, I only want to remove the last bit of the output, and so I am simply using something like:

```
<%= @object.address.to_s.chomp(', USA') %>
```

for any given instance.

However, I would like to know if there is a more dynamic option to return only the zip code, only the country, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@object` you are working with is likely an instance of [`Geocoder::Result::Google`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result/Google).

If you look at the docs for [`Geocoder::Result::Google`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result/Google) you'll notice that there are several methods for accessing components of an address like zip code, country, etc.

Here are some examples

```
address = @object.address
puts address.postal_code  #=> 10010
puts address.city         #=> Manhattan
puts address.state_code   #=> NY
puts address.country_code #=> USA
```

If the component you are looking for isn't available in a method you can use `address_components_of_type` directly.

```
puts @object.address_components_of_type(:street_number) #=> 1600
```

You can find the full list of components here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types